# c++ Intel inspector shows many errors with boost - do I need to worry?

Tags: c++, memory-management, boost, intel-inspector

I have a problem with my current program. For some reason it always crashed after the final line of code on windows. I got a "application is no longer responding" error or something like this. 
So I tried the Intel inspector. And Luckily it told me some bad errors in my project where I accessed some uninitialized memory.

Besides this obvious problems that I understand I get also some:

- Incorrect memcpy calls in: `boost::algorithm::trim()`
- Uninitialized partial memory access in: `myptree.get<boost::posix_time::ptime>("path.to.node")` where `myptree` is of type `boost::property_tree::ptree`
- Uninitialized memory access in: `cout << myptime` where `myptime` is of type `boost::posix_time::ptime`

...

does this mean that I use the boost library functions not properly? Or are this false positives?

I'm just confused because the functions work, they do what I want them to do and I get no error message.

I also get a Memory not deallocated warning at the end (from [Unknown] source).

example for trim:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <boost/algorithm/string.hpp>
int main() {
    std::string test = " test  ";

    boost::algorithm::trim(test);
    std::cout << test << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

gives me a incorrect memcpy call...

Comment: #3 `cout << myptime` I doubt this is in boost.  If you're using uninitialised memory then you're swimming in undefined behaviour land, and anything could happen in the next half hour

Comment: If you can create a trivial example program that reproduces the generation of the error-messages, and include that program in your question, that would help people determine where the underlying fault is located.

Comment: Hello, sry for the late reply, I have added an example

Answer (score 1):

Boost will happily forward bad arguments; it often has no way to check them. If boost::algorithm::trim passes a bad argument to memcpy, it will be because you passes a bad argument to trim.

So, yes, you should worry. There are almost certainly  multiple bugs in your program. Check your calls to the functions reported.